# If $F$ is a radical extension of $K$ and $E$ is an intermediate field, then $F$ is a radical extension of $E$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to prove that if $F$ is a radical extension of $K$ and $E$ is an intermediate field, then $F$ is a radical extension of $E$.

I thought about the proof and wanted to apply this fact: if $F$ is a radical extension field of $K$ and $E$ is an intermediate field, then $\mathrm{Aut}_KE$ is a solvable group. But I don't know how to proceed from here. Am I on a right track?

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from the definition? "A radical extension of a field is an extension that is obtained by adjoining a sequence of $n$th roots of elements."

Comment: @GregMartin Actually it is. Thanks for your input. I was worried that there might be something deeper than it looks.